# Integral of $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} \frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{f'(x)}df(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am wondering if it is possible to compute the integral $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} \frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{f'(x)}df(x)$ somehow without expanding $df(x)$. Thanks.

Comment: What is $x'$? Is $x$ a function of something?

Comment: What's $x'$? the derivative of $x$? if yes, $x'=1$

Comment: Sorry. I have re-edited my question. It should be $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{f'(x)}\,\mathrm df(x)=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{f'(x)}f'(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{f(x)}\,\mathrm dx$$
This is not possible *in general*, though it could be possible if $f(x)$ was 'nice' enough. An example where it is not possible is $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is actually not nice. It is in the form of $a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(C)$ (law of cosine), where $b$ and $C$ both depend on $x$. My purpose is to keep the form of $f(x)$ after integration, hoping it would cancel out with some existing term of $f(x)$ outside this integral. Guess it would not work then.

Comment: @VincentGao hmm, yes that does sound tricky